# Is there any way to transform a non-convex optimization problem into a convex one?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I have an optimization problem which is described as

$$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize}_x & c^{T}x\\
\text{subject to} & Gx \preceq h\\
                  & -x^{T}Px - qx - r \leq 0
\end{array}$$

where $P$ is positive semidefinite. Is there any way to convert this problem into a convex problem?

Comment: No, there is not. See [this PDF](http://web.stanford.edu/class/ee392o/relaxations.pdf) for some heuristic alternatives.